# create a double array with dimention taken from file

Tags: c++

Hey I'm having trouble with this part of code:

```
ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open ("input.txt");

int n;

inputfile >> n;

int dist[n][n]{};

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            inputfile >> dist[i][j];
        }
}
```

this doesn't run, but this:

```
ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open ("input.txt");

int n;

inputfile >> n;

int dist[6][6]{};

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            inputfile >> dist[i][j];
        }
}
```

does...

I want to take the dimension of the double array from the input file, however I get this compilation error code:

> internal compiler error: in make_decl_rtl, at varasm.c:1322"

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Doesn't compile?  Doesn't link?  Doesn't run?  Doesn't run correctly?  Are you given messages describing the problem?

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain. It doesn't run. I have this error: "internal compiler error: in make_decl_rtl, at varasm.c:1322"

Comment: You can't define array dimensions dynamically. It's not legal C++ though some compilers will let you. Still, it's not portable. You are likely using one that doesn't provide that extension.

Comment: You should edit your post to include the compiler output.

Comment: ok. thanks. But there's no way of reading a double array from a file without knowing before what is the dimension of that array?

Comment: @LauraPinguicha think of the fun you could have debugging your program if you could allocate a dynamically sized object in the relatively small Automatic storage space. Some user could be a wiseguy and request millions of elements. Really easy way to cause a stack overflow.

Comment: @LauraPinguicha It is possible and easy. 1) Read about dynamic arrays 2) Use dynamic arrays

Comment: You should probably report this to your compiler's developers. If Variable Length Arrays are allowed by the compiler this should work. If not, you should get a meaningful error message. You should not be able to crash the compiler.

Comment: If an answer solved your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

As doug has stated, in C++, you cannot create arrays dynamically; the dimensions of a plain array must be predetermined and known at compile-time.

In order to achieve an array with dimensions that are variable at run-time, you need to use a type that uses dynamic allocation, [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/).

Comment: Use of STL to qualify containers from the standard library is an anachronism.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic version would be:

```
ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open ("input.txt");

int n;

inputfile >> n;

int* dist = new int[n*n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            inputfile >> dist[i*n+j];
        }
}
delete[] dist;
```

But it as soon as you want to do more with the array: it is better to switch to `std::vector`, which handels all the allocation and reallocation for you.